# Как спрятать ссылку?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Меня интересует вопрос: как спрятать ссылку при помощи `javascript`, да так чтобы поисковый бот его не воспринимал как ссылку. Чтобы нужные ссылки находились в отдельном файле `javascript`.

Мне рекомендовали прятать при помощи библиотек `query`. Вернее сказать, я видел, как это делали на видео курсе. Но когда я все в точности повторил, ссылку не увидел. Возможно, это из-за того, что у меня файлы с контентом подключены к шаблону дизайна по средствам php кода. А может просто где-то ошибка в примере.

Ответ нужен подробный мой уровень в `javascript` чуть больше нуля.

Answer (score 1):

При генерации страницы на php вместо ссылок создавайте, span (к примеру) с нужной информацией:

```
<span class="plink" data-u="{url ссылки}">название ссылки</span>
```

далее в js добавляем преобразование в настоящую ссылку:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.plink').each(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith('<a href="'+$(this).data('u')+'" target="_blank" class="link">'+$(this).html()+'</a>')
  })
})
```

Таким образом у вас будут простые тексты в момент генерации страницы и они же видны поисковикам. А после рендеринга странички в браузере и выполнении js элементы заменятся на ссылки. Стоит так же отметить про необходимость задать стили для классов "plink" и "link". Желательно, что бы они выглядели одинаково и тогда это не будет напрягать пользователя (в момент замены). Классы взял разные, так как могут понадобиться некоторое отличие в стилях :)

P.S. Так же желательно избегать всякого рода названий схожих с ссылкой. Имеется ввиду не самый лучший способ называть класс link, url и подобное. Так как гуглобот все-таки пытается анализировать контент и обнаруживать ссылки (умный зараза). Лучше дать какие-то понятные для вас технические классы и просто это запомнить.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<p>Вообще, это не самый лучший вариант, но если хочется, то кликни по <span id='link42' class='link'>псевдо-ссылке</span>.</p>
```

В jQuery делаем обработчик:

```
$(function(){
    $('#link42').click(function(){
        window.open("http://site.ru/", '_self');
    });
});
```

И обязательно делаем *span* похожим на ссылку:

```
.link {
   cursor: pointer;
   color: #00f;
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: Тогда еще вопрос. Как привязать файл квери к документу, и какого расширения документы квери, чем отличаются от яваскрипт?

Comment: [jQuery – Javascript нового поколения](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/inet/jQuery.xml)